# Databind with Chart controls gives NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, charts

I feed a Microsoft Chart control with a IEnumerable of my own class ChartPoint

```
    public class ChartPoint
    {
        public double Xvalue { get; set; }
        public double Yvalue { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Tooltip { get; set; }
    }
```

then i tries to DataBind the IEnumerable< ChartPoint>:

```
serie.Points.DataBind(points, "Xvalue", "Yvalue", "Tooltip=Tooltip,Url=Url");
```

but i then hits a NotImplementedException on that row:

```
 System.Linq.Iterator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset() +29
   System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPointCollection.DataBind(IEnumerable dataSource, String xField, String yFields, String otherFields) +313
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using a C# iterator?

C# iterators do not implement the Reset function on the generated IEnumerator and will throw a NotImplementedException if it is called.  It looks like the particular control requires that method to be present.

You will likely have to use a collection which supports Reset on it's iterator.  The easiest way to achieve this is to use a `List<T>` to wrap your existing `IEnumerable<T>`

For example

```
List<ChartPoint> list = new List<ChartPoint>(points);
serie.Points.DataBind(list, "Xvalue", "Yvalue", "Tooltip=Tooltip,Url=Url");
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using iterator blocks (i.e. `yield return`)?  The compiler <del>won't generate a `Reset` method if you do</del> generates a `Reset` method but the method throws a `NotImplementedException`.

Comment: Minor correction. It does generate a Reset (IEnumerator<T> requires it), it just throws a NotImplementedException

Answer (score 0):

See my bug report on Connect [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=507920). Please vote for this and maybe MS will fix it in the next Chart release.